# Scala implicit parameters with defaults defined in the companion object

Tags: scala, scope, implicit

According to the Scala Spec (2.8), for an implicit to be found it must be defined in local scope, inherited scope, or in a **companion** object.  Given that, it seems to me that the following code should work *without an explicit import of the contents of the companion object*.  I see this used in the Scala library source (eg. CanBuildFrom).  It also seems that I should be able to call XX.foo() from outside the definition of the XX class and have my implicit parameter from the companion class used.  What am I missing?

```
object XX {
   implicit def XYZ[T]: (T) => Unit = null
}

class XX {
  // import XX._     // Works with this line uncommented...
  def foo(s: String)(implicit f: (String) => Unit): Unit = {
    if (f == null)
      println("Just: " + s)
    else
      f(s)
  }

  def bar {
    foo("abc"){ s => println("Func: " + s)}
    foo("xyz")  // <-- Compile error here: could not find implicit value for parameter f
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always interpreted the spec to mean that the implicit can be defined in the companion object of the implicit parameter, not the class containing the definition.  Something like this:

```
object ZZ {
   implicit val xyz: ZZ = new ZZ()
}
class ZZ {
  def bar: (String) => Unit = null
}

class XX {
  def foo(s: String)(implicit f: ZZ): Unit = {
    if (f.bar == null)
      println("Just: " + s)
    else
      f.bar(s)
  }

  def bar {
    foo("xyz")
  }
}
```

It seems clear in Section 7.2 of the spec:

> The actual arguments that are eligible
>   to be passed to an implicit parameter
>   of type T fall into two categories.
>   First, eligible are all identiﬁers x
>   that can be accessed at the point of
>   the method call without a preﬁx and
>   that denote an implicit deﬁnition
>   (§7.1) or an implicit parameter. An
>   eligible identiﬁermay thus be a local
>   name, or a member of an enclosing
>   template, or it may be have been made
>   accessible without a preﬁx through an
>   import clause (§4.7). If there are no
>   eligible identiﬁers under this rule,
>   then, second, eligible are also all
>   **implicit members of some object that
>   belongs to the implicit scope of the
>   implicit parameter’s type, T.**

Can you quote the part that indicates the companion object of the containing class of the definition?

Comment: Seems I misunderstood which class the companion object had to be associated with.  Thanks for clearing it up for me.  I'm trying to find a way to define a "default function" that can be passed to another function. But can be overridden by the caller.

Comment: I assume your "default function" could be implemented as a default argument.  http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2075